# ID selectors in IE9 not recognized

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm dealing with a weird issue in relation to `CSS` and `IE9`. The site is a couple less sheets compiled into one site.css. The site looks fine and the way it should in every browser including IE8, which usually I need to work on with conditional styles and such. However for some reason in IE9, it's just terrible.

Digging through dev tools and checking the styles, it looks like in several areas it not picking up on the ID selectors. So since I'll have an ID with nested class selectors below, none of those classes are being styled as well.

I've looked into the selector limit, as someone else has noted in another question on here and I'm at `3950` selectors, so don't think that is the issue.

Another thing I've checked in the meta tag which I have:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Lastly I have my DOCTYPE declared:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
```

It's a really strange issue, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: do you have an example of your code?

Comment: Solution posted below. It was file size related.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the same ID several times on your website, so it only picks up the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, did a quick traverse of the source as IE and Chrome renders it and the ID selectors only appear once on the page.

Comment: This has never been the case in any browser, not even IE. I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being file size related, I read somewhere that the file size is limited to 278kb. I split the stylesheet into two smaller files and bam all the styles were properly rendered. Wish I would've checked that earlier spent several hours racking my brain over this.